# Payment types in receipts

Tags: meaning

If I find one of the following words on a receipt before the total sum:

- クレジット
- クレジット支払
- クレジット支払額
- クレジット計
- クレジット売上

Can I conclude that the transaction was paid for by credit card?

And what does it mean when I see the two letters `(MS)` in parentheses after the card number?  For example: `XXXXXXXXXXXX1234 (MS)`

PS1: Answer for second comment - there is only one of this words on a receipt. There is no numbers after word except total sum usually.

Comment: Could MS just be for "magnetic strip" (磁気ストライプカード), indicating how the card was scanned (as opposed to ICカード, where you read the info from the chip and put your PIN in)

Comment: Are these all on the same receipt? Do they have numbers next to them?

Answer (score 4):

Let me ask you a similar question in English: “If I find the word ‘credit’ on a receipt on the same line as the total sum, can I conclude that the transaction was paid for by credit card?”  I do not know any concrete case where you cannot, but I cannot guarantee that it never means anything else unless I see the whole receipt.  After all, understanding a text for sure requires more than pattern matching.

Comment: However if you see クレジット支払(額) then you can probably pretty safely assume that much was paid by credit.

Comment: The only examples in English I can think of are if for some reason the person was owed money back by the company. You can have store credit (for example after returning an item) or an account with a business could be 'in credit' (if you were overcharged and then it was corrected).  I don't know if these would be called クレジット in Japanese, though.